# Are there silicon wireless keyboards for apple machines?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard

I have a macbook-pro & mac-mini. Typing is easy on macbook since the keyboard is silicon. That's not the case with apple wireless keyboard which is connected to the mac-mini, keys are slippery. Speed typing is not easy like on macbook.

My Question is,
Are there keyboards with silicon keys for apple computers ? Where can I buy them ?

Or Can I replace keys on Wireless Keyboard with keys on macbook keyboard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can purchase a Moshi ClearGuard keyboard protector [directly from Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/product/TW462LL/A/moshi-clearguard-cs-keyboard-protector-for-apple-keyboard) and use it on your wireless keyboard. I have one in use at home in the kitchen/family room for our AppleTV 3rd gen. Comes in handy when I'm cooking and want to use the keyboard as a remote without having to wash my hands!

BTW/ Silicon is an element (#14 on the Periodic table.) Silicone is a flexible synthetic polymer used for adhesives, lubricants, cook-wear, insulation, and water-proofing.

Comment: Thank You for the answer, I thought that protector was just to cover and keep the keyboard somewhere safe :).Thank You again.